# Is there a way to Annotate Asp.NET-Identity Properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I was previously creating a project using MVC4/EF5 and have started a new project (for simplest method) and started recreating what I have so far in MVC5/EF6 to, among other things, make use of the ASP.NET Identity.

In my `IdentityModels.cs` I have added several properties such as [NAME], [POSITION], [LASTVISITDATE], etc. On the `IdentityModel.cs` properties I have also added `Grid.MVC` [Data Annotations](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Data%20annotations) which allow me to quickly and easily display a tabled and paged layout of specific Models properties to a View.

Now, I have all of my old code functioning effectively, but the `Asp.NET Identity` properties such as [PasswordHash], [SecurityStamp], [TwoFactorEndabled], etc. are also showing up inside my Grid.MVC.

Is there any way for me to give these `Identity` properties the Grid.MVC annotation of [NotMappedColumn], or will I need to scratch my use of Grid.MVC for something else?

I'd really like to use my Grid.MVC method to display data in my view if at all possible as with a few small annotations on the model I am able to render all the data as I wish with some short coding within the View:

```
<div class="overflowPrevention">

    @*Images in Columns: https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/discussions/440977*@

    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "UserManage", new { id = o.Id }, null));
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(u => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "UserManage", new { id = u.Id }, null));
            columns.Insert(2, u => u.ProfilePictureUrl).Titled("User Img").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(u => @<img class="" src="@u.ProfilePictureUrl" alt="Current Profile Image" width="75px" height="75px" />);

        }).AutoGenerateColumns()
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to create a viewmodel for your view, which only contains the necessary properties, instead of having your view being strongly typed to your domain user model.

Comment: Will I still be able to use ASP.Net Identity when performing my CRUD actions? I was wondering if you could provide an example? I'm still pretty new to MVC and a lot of what I know is what I've done before and know works, but not necessarily me knowing HOW it works I'm sad to say.

Comment: Sure you will, as you're just passing the ID of the user to your controller action anyways, you would need to fetch the User again.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I may try this out if a more needed situation comes up. It's slightly more code than using the `AutoGenerateColumns()`, but I opted to instead `Add()` each column I desired individually and thus only show the Model properties I want. It's slightly more code in the View, but less code in the Model.